# how to add a click handler without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a basic click handler to an element using ID. Normally I would use jQuery, but I have forgotten how to do it in vanilla js.

What is the best way to do this, without using jQuery:

```
$("#myBasic").click(function(){
  alert(“testString”);
});
```

Comment: How exactly is this question ambiguous? It's a very clear, concise question. Stop closing questions just because they're too basic for your taste.

Comment: Agreed, @thomasruns. I found this Q&A helpful upon googling "vanilla javascript add click handler" and it's just what I needed.

Comment: I also found this helpful, because I have the same exact question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very basic way is to just assign a function to the `on[event]` property of the element

```
document.getElementById("myBasic").onclick = function() { 
                                                 alert("testString");
                                             };
```

This has very broad browswer support, and is useful for most basic cases

---

There are other event handling features as well, like [`.addEventListener(evt, fn, capture)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), but IE only started supporting it in IE9. Before that, you'd need to use `attachEvent(onevt, fn)`, which is similar, but not identical.

The main trouble with `.attachEvent()` is that it doesn't give you an automatic reference to the element that bound the handler via `this`. But there are workarounds for that.

---

To create a fairly browser compatible solution, you could do something like this:

```
function addListener(elem, type, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(type, fn, false);

    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + type, function() {
                                          return fn.call(elem, window.event);
                                       });
    } else {
        elem["on" + type] = fn;
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myBasic");

addListener(el, "click", function(e) { alert(this.id); });
```

This should cover most situations, though I'd be a little concerned about memory leaks for the `.attachEvent` version.

---

All this only deals with binding the handler. To obtain consistent cross-browser behavior, you'd likely need to have a fix ready for the `event` object.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest is just:

```
document.getElementById('myBasic').onclick = function() {
    // do something
};
```

The most correct way is:

```
var f = function() {
    // do something
};
if( document.body.attachEvent)
    document.getElementById('myBasic').attachEvent("onclick",f);
else
    document.getElementById('myBasic').addEventListener("click",f);
```

Comment: why is that the most correct way ?

Comment: Because it allows you to attach multiple handlers, whereas repeatedly assigning to `onclick` will overwrite old ones. The second one also includes browser compatibility by checking which method to use.

Comment: You may want to test for `.addEventListener` instead of `.attachEvent`, so that IE9+ will use the *"best"* one.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('myBasic').addEventListener("click",function(){alert("teststring")});
```